# Attach to ganache-cli using geth

Tags: go-ethereum, ganache

Is it possible to attach with `geth` to `ganache-cli`?

I start `ganache-cli` like this:

```
ganache-cli --db ~/ganache -i 15
```

Then I try to attach to the chain like this:

```
geth --datadir ~/ganache/ --networkid 15 attach
```

This is the error I get:

```
Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix /root/ganache/geth.ipc: connect: no such file or directory
```

If I start a private chain using `geth` directly, I can attach to it without any problems.

```
geth --datadir ~/mychain --rpc --rpcapi eth,net,web3 --nodiscover --networkid 15 --bootnodes {URI}
geth --datadir ~/mychain --networkid 15 attach
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are running ganache at 8545:

`geth attach http://127.0.0.1:8545`